# After the Cold War, how did Berlin develop so much more rapidly than Moscow?

Tags: soviet-union, germany

How did Berlin redevelop so rapidly that today its economy is way better than Moscow's following the Cold War?

Comment: Perhaps if some objective difference was added to the question to talk about, it would help. For instance, GDP growth numbers for the two cities may be available somewhere.

Comment: Your question is very unclear and, in the current form, unanswerable, but if you want to understand the development of East Berlin after 1990, consider the amount one money invested into its infrastructure by the German Federal government. Start by taking a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_reunification#Cost_of_reunification).

Comment: @MoisheKohan, suggest you revise the question based on those assumptions and then pose an answer; I would upvote that Q&A

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace It probably will get closed before I get my act together.

Comment: Do you realize that East Germany did **join** West Germany, which was about four times larger at that point? West Germany provided money, experts, stability, and an existing legal/political framework which overwhelmed anything the GDP revolutionaries might have proposed.

Comment: Also compare the other countries of eastern Europe that were liberated after the fall of the USSR.

Comment: Solidaritätszuschlag and the fact that the GDR became part of the Federal Republic of Germany. Nothing more.

Comment: The mearging of both city administrations (Magistrat and Senat) started in June 1990 after the Magistrat had been elected in May of that year. The removal of the Wall, reopening of streets, reconnection of gas electricity, public transportation etc. were the main tasks at that time. The existing city districts simply continued. The first common election took place in December and the constitution of Berlin (West) was taken over in January 1991. 1995, the final constitution had been passed and confirmed by a referendum.

Comment: @Trish Actually there was a lot more than that. For Berlin it was relatively simple since the administration structure was similar. For the newly (re-)founded states the administrations had to be rebuilt from scratch. Each new state had a sponsor state, which assisted with the buildup of the new administration until the 1990's when it was no longer needed.

Comment: @jamesqf The situation for the other former socialist countries was far more difficult, since these administrations had to envolve from a totalitarian system, often with peaple who had been trained by such systems and could not always be trusted or simply lacked the practical experience needed to deal with problems in a democratic mannor. Police, justice reforms were the problem #1.

Comment: I did a first crack at editing this, fixing up the title and the first paragraph. I didn't touch the later 2 because frankly I don't understand what they are asking. Could we have some clarification on that? What kind of "bad reputation" are we talking about? What makes you think having been a "puppet state" has relevance to the question?

Comment: Given that I modhammered this closed, I've modhammered it open. I deleted the two questions that none of us could understand - if @victor can explain them we can add them back.  But I think the question as now stands can be answered.

Comment: @Mark Johnson: True, but my impression is that those  other countries still have generally done better than Russia.

Answer (score 2):

**Berlin, not East Berlin**

To begin with, there is no such place anymore as East Berlin, as can be confirmed by Wikipedia, and therefore it is impossible for East Berlin since 1990 to have competed with Moscow in anyway shape or form.

[East Berlin, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Berlin)

> East Berlin was the de facto capital city of the German Democratic Republic from 1949 to 1990.

[East Berlin Coat of arms by MaddenMadden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Berlin#/media/File:Coat_of_arms_of_Berlin_(1935).svg)
[image: Coat of arms of East Berlin]

**West Berlin**

Now, before 1990, there was also a "West Berlin", and unlike East Berlin that suffered greatly, West Berlin was controlled by its Western allies during the cold war, and was actually a wealthy city, according to Wikipedia and the book " Divided, But Not Disconnected".

[West Berlin, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Berlin#cite_note-1)

> West Berlin was formally controlled by the Western Allies and was entirely surrounded by the Soviet-controlled East Berlin and East Germany. West Berlin had great symbolic significance during the Cold War, as it was widely considered by westerners an "island of freedom". It was heavily subsidised by West Germany as a "showcase of the West".[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Berlin)

[image: Divided but not disconnected]

**Berlin**

Therefore, as West Berlin and East Berlin merged in 1990 after the fall of the Berlin wall, i assume that you mean simply Berlin, and historically Berlin has always been a large and wealthy metropolis, and a prime location for financial institutions such as banks, according to Wikipedia.

[Economy of Berlin, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_Berlin)

> Berlin became one of the largest and most advanced industrial centers in Europe after 1870. After 1900 the Berlin banking district became a major continental financial center and was home to a number of prominent banks.

[Berlin 1847, by Karl Eduard Biermann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_Berlin#/media/File:Maschinenbau-Anstalt_Borsig,_Berlin_Chausseestra%C3%9Fe,_1847,_Karl_Eduard_Biermann.jpg) 
[image: Train factory of August Borsig in 1847.]

**Geography**

The reason for Berlins success is put down to geography and its convenient and close proximity to the river spree which offers[ed] an amazing trade route.

[History, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_Berlin#History)

> Berlin was founded at a point where trade routes crossed the river Spree and it quickly became a commercial center.

[River spree, by Jorge Royan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spree#/media/File:Berlin-_Bundestag_by_the_Spree_-_3570.jpg)
[image: Bundestag by the Spree. Paul Löbe and Marie-Elisabeth Lüders House in the German Government Buildings, near the Reichstag. Platz]

**Berlin 10% unemployment**

Now, it all depends on what criteria we are using when deciding which country has outgrown which.

To begin with Berlin has a [10% unemployment rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_German_states_by_unemployment_rate)

**Moscow 1.5% unemployment**

Now, using the exact same wikipedia graph for Russia, we see that in comparison to Berlins 10% unemployment rate, Moscow has only a [1.5% unemployment rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_federal_subjects_of_Russia_by_unemployment_rate).

**Berlin 31 universities**

According to Wikipedia Berlin has [31 universities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universities_and_research_institutions_in_Berlin#cite_note-2)

**Moscow 60 universities**

In comparison to Berlins 31 universities, moscow has [60 universities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Universities_in_Moscow) according to Wikipedia

**Berlin Metro population 6,144,600**

According to Wikipedia Berlin has a Metro population of [6,144,600](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin)

**Moscow Metro population 20,004,462**

And in comparison to Berlins 6,144,600 residents, Moscow has a metro population of [20,004,462](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow)

**After the Cold War, how did East Berlin develop so much more rapidly than Moscow?** The question is actually a little bit of a paradox, as whilst Berlin being more developed than Moscow is debatable, it is in fact true that Berlins economic rise has been sudden and meteoric, but this can easily be explained with a little bit of lateral thinking. Quite simply, Moscow was never devastated by world war 2 and never suffered the hardships of being partitioned like Berlin did, and so they have not required to rebuild, like Berlin has.

[economy of Berlin, wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_Berlin)

> Berlin's economy has been affected through the years by the city's changing geopolitical fortunes from 1961-1989. The city stagnated economically during the Cold War, when West Berlin was isolated geographically and East Berlin suffered from poor economic decisions made by East Germany’s socialist central planners.

[image: Berlin wall]

**Bonn to Berlin**

The most critical factor in Berlins rise back to their potential was the move of the Federal government from Bonn to Berlin, which brought with it thousands of jobs.

[Reunification, wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_Berlin#Reunification)

> The move of the federal government from Bonn to Berlin in 1999 brought some economic stimulus and tens of thousands of jobs from government employees, parliamentary services, lobbyists and journalism to Berlin. Berlin’s service sectors have also benefited from improved transportation and communications links to the surrounding region.

[Federal government headquarters by Diego Delso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Chancellery#/media/File:Canciller%C3%ADa_Federal,_Berl%C3%ADn,_Alemania,_2016-04-21,_DD_37-39_HDR.JPG)
[image: Federal government headquarters]

Comment: Sorry, but this is a badly compiled collection of wikipedia information without any understanding of the background or the situation. The present population of Berlin is less than 4 million, with the highest amount just under 4.5 million in the 1930's and 1940's (and not over 6 million as claimed).

Comment: @Mark Johnson Metro population is what i used. This includes surrounding areas.. I clearly state this. "metro population".

Comment: You are lumping the population and infrastructure of 2 separate states togeather and treating them as one. The latter is mainly rural and a compleatly different set of priorities.

Comment: What does the main train station (Hauptbahnhof) have to do with 'Government headquarters'?

Comment: @Mark Johnson Population (31 December 2019)[2] • City/State 3,769,495 • Urban[3] 4,473,100 • Metro[4] 6,144,600.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin ... It is on the right hand side of the screen for berlin..It is a copy and paste.. A metro area is not a seperate state. It is the area just outside the city. Suburbs.

Comment: @Mark Johnson thank you for pointing out the wrong photo. Corrected

Comment: The picture of the railway headquarters is not much better. The cities of Potsdam, Brandenburg, Frankfurt/Oder etc. are not suburbs of Berlin and should not be lumped togeather in your conclusions.

Comment: @Mark Johnson nope, that was still the wrong building, struggling to find the correct one from my downloads, but found it now

Comment: @Mark Johnson. You were correct about the picture. but wrong about frankfurt et cetera. That is not what a metro population is. It is like City of London, then greater london.

Comment: As someone who lives in Berlin, I can assure you that the very loose cooperation between the states Berlin and Brandenburg, which came about after a refused referendum to merge both states, is different from what is normally understood as  a Metropolen area and is even often counter productive. For this topic/question (development of eastern Berlin after 1990), the area outside of Berlin should be left out.

Comment: @Mark Johnson Thank you for the help in improving my answer. I appreciate it. Here is my understanding of a metropolitan area https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolitan_area ...I am going to the travel section now to settle this and if your case is backed up i will change it to urban population, which will greatly reduce the questioners point, as i used the metro area to give his case more validity regards to berlin being huge. Please do not respond in the travel section, as it would be unfair for you to influence the answers. i will not influence either

Comment: This condition is not fullfilled: **under the same administrative division, sharing industry, infrastructure and housing**. Different state laws apply for Education, housing, building laws, pilice, justice  etc.

Comment: So... who wins, according to these numbers? Moscow with lower unemployment or Berlin with more universities per capita?..

Comment: Brandenburg has the second-lowest population density of all German Länder (after Mecklenburg-Vorpommern). Counting all those people as inhabitants of a metropolitan region is really sloppy. Counting Potsdam and even Strausberg might be acceptable, but certainly not Uckermark or Prignitz.